# Apply Conditional Formatting to Data Range 1 Based on Values in Data Range 2

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply a conditional format that identifies which top 10 customers per country are under/over performing average by margin.

Data Table Layout:

[image]

So I have populated customer IDs based on total profit, but I need to highlight the those that are performing well and not so well by profit margin. This will be used for reporting and need to eliminate the actual margin numbers and just have the data matrix of customer IDs ranked in order of total profit and highlight based on margin performance. So ultimately I am applying the output from the conditional format of data table two to data table one.

Thanks,

SWD

Comment: Please, include some relevant code you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you not use the inbuilt conditional formatting ?

Comment: @QHarr You can use formulas to reference values in other cells, but then you lose the ability to use a continuous 3-Color scale.

Comment: This question is pretty closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841839/apply-3-color-scale-to-an-entire-row-in-excel-2010

Comment: @AlexisOlson  many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to "copy" the conditional formatting as it is displayed in your 2nd table and apply that format to the cells in your first table. Something like this should work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteConFormatAsRealFormat()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
    Dim fromRng As Range, toRng As Range, rw As Long, col As Long

    Set fromRng = ws.Range("B10:F14") ' Range with conditional format
    Set toRng = ws.Range("B2:F6") ' Same number of rows/columns as fromRng

    For col = 1 To toRng.Columns.Count
        For rw = 1 To toRng.Rows.Count
            toRng.Cells(rw, col).Interior.Color = fromRng.Cells(rw, col).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        Next rw
    Next col

End Sub
```